# What to do with "Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks" error?

Tags: python, python-playsound

I have a piece of code that plays a sound using the playsound module but the file location gives an error:

```
import playsound

playsound.playsound('C:\\Users\\nc_ma\\Downloads\\Note1.mp3')
```

error:

```
Error 305 for command:
    open "C:\Users\nc_ma\Downloads\Note1.mp3"
Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks.
```

Comment: Try co convert it into raw string

Comment: Maybe it's related to https://githubmemory.com/repo/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/75 ? I didn't dig deeper.

Comment: @Sujay converting to raw string doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I tried another way:
I used `os`

```py
import os
os.startfile('path\\file.filetype')
```

and it started working
for you:

```
os.startfile('C:\\Users\\nc_ma\\Downloads\\Note1.mp3')
```

or

```py
from playsound import playsound
playsound('Path\\File Name.mp3')
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue of Error 305 . Check your playsound version. There is an issue with version 1.3. Downgrading to version 1.2.2 worked for me.

Follow the below steps:

```
pip uninstall playsound
pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

Run the same file again. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The python package playsound is effectively broken. I made a replacement here:

```
https://github.com/zackees/playaudio
```

Which can be installed via:

```
pip install playaudio
```

Keep in mind this is a blocking library. So you'll need to wrap it in a thread if you want to want async behavior.